# Unable to calling unmanaged C++ from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-c++

How to call this expose c++ (PAApi.dll) code from c# ??

```
Long PAHandShake( long lOperationCode, const TCHAR * sServerAddress, pPAEvent pEventFunc )
```

Parameters:

- lOperationCode = The code of the operation required.
- sServerAddress = Address of the server.
- pEventFunc – Pointer to callback event function. The function prototype is as follows:

  typedef long (*pPAEvent)(long, long, const TCHAR *)

Return value:

- The return value determines whether the operation succeeds or not.

I try below code, but it doesn't work

```
   public class TestDll
    {    
        [DllImport("PAApi.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern long PAHandShake(long operationCode, string serverAddress, pPAEvent callback);
        
        public delegate long pPAEvent(long a, long b, string c);

        public TestDll()
        {
            Test();
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            
            pPAEvent cb = new pPAEvent(Callback);
            PAHandShake(1, "127.0.0.1", Callback);
        }

        //Trying to implement this method through callback    
        public static long Callback(long a, long b, string c)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I got the following error...

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'PAApi.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libPAApi.dll, 1): image not found
```

dyld log

```
dyld: loaded: <3741BCB4-F66C-34E5-99B5-5C8E70F3541C> /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
dyld: loaded: <B217D905-4F9C-3DE0-8844-88FAA3C2C851> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: <83503CE0-32B1-36DB-A4F0-3CC6B7BCF50A> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: loaded: <3C9FE530-3CD2-3A64-8A36-70816AEBDF0D> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
dyld: loaded: <1A98B064-8FED-39CF-BB2E-5BDA1EF5B65A> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
dyld: loaded: <822A29CE-BF54-35AD-BB15-8FAECB800C7D> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: <62EE1D14-5ED7-3CEC-81C0-9C93833641F1> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
dyld: loaded: <39DBE613-135B-3AFE-A6AF-7898A37F70C2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
dyld: loaded: <1EB11CFB-ABD7-36DD-97C7-C112A6601416> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: <AD988EEA-1A2F-3404-9A6E-390FC2504223> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
dyld: loaded: <4641E48F-75B5-3CC7-8263-47BF79F15394> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
dyld: loaded: <803F6AED-99D5-3CCF-B0FA-361BCF14C8C0> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
dyld: loaded: <C7C51322-8491-3B78-9CFA-2B4753662BCF> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
dyld: loaded: <C2584BC4-497B-3170-ADDF-21B8E10B4DFD> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
dyld: loaded: <40D35D75-524B-3DA6-8159-E7E0FA66F5BC> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
dyld: loaded: <5CC12A16-82CB-32F0-9040-72CFC88A48DF> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
dyld: loaded: <5B48071E-85EB-33B0-AE9B-127AEB398AEC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E644CAA0-65B7-36E4-8041-520F3301F3DB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
dyld: loaded: <4AF71812-4099-3E96-B271-1F259491A2B2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
dyld: loaded: <C53D5E0C-0C4F-3B35-A24B-E0D7101A3F95> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_collections.dylib
dyld: loaded: <4917D824-4DE8-32CC-9ED2-1FBF371FEB9F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
dyld: loaded: <6F08275F-B912-3D8E-9D74-4845158AE4F3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
dyld: loaded: <529A0663-A936-309C-9318-1B04B7F70658> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E016D8F7-C87F-36F8-B8A0-6A61B8E4BACB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E0A0CAB3-6779-3C83-AC67-046CFE69F9C2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
dyld: loaded: <9CECB43A-094E-3CA9-B730-24DEA1A6DE05> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
dyld: loaded: <0C96CFE8-71F5-3335-8423-581BC3DE5846> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
dyld: loaded: <DD26CC5C-AFF6-305F-A567-14909DD57163> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
dyld: loaded: <A498D1EF-E43D-310C-84E8-9C0AADA0C475> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
dyld: loaded: <5213D866-7D0E-3FD9-8E1A-03C0E39CEC44> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
dyld: loaded: <B2BF20C7-448A-3FBD-A2F5-AB7618D173F6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
dyld: loaded: <20310EE6-2C3F-361A-9ECA-4223AFC03B65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_product_info_filter.dylib
dyld: loaded: <5F7F3DD1-4B38-310C-AA8F-19FF1B0F5276> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E05E35BC-1BAB-365B-8BEE-D774189EFD3B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
dyld: loaded: <AB413518-ECDE-3F04-A61C-278D3CF43076> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
dyld: loaded: <1C3E1A0A-92A8-3CDE-B622-8940B43A5DF2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
dyld: loaded: <B989DF6C-ADFE-3AF9-9C91-07D2521F9E47> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
dyld: loaded: <BC85B46C-02EE-31FF-861D-F0DE01E8F6CF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
dyld: loaded: <87FEF600-48D9-31C9-B8FC-D5249B2AE95D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
dyld: loaded: <1D0A4B4A-4370-3548-8DC1-42A7B4BD45D3> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
dyld: loaded: <70F26262-01AA-3CEC-9FAD-2701D24096F0> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
dyld: loaded: <EB6B543F-D42C-3FB2-A2EC-43407C5F80D3> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: <44C477D9-013F-3A6D-A9FE-68A89214E6A5> /usr/lib/liboah.dylib
dyld: loaded: <AF874520-5DCD-31A4-9213-7C120ED78E6F> /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/3.1.13/libhostfxr.dylib
dyld: loaded: <FBC7738A-6C76-3F6A-A423-618952AB5A48> /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.13/libhostpolicy.dylib
dyld: loaded: <961A9335-3B4A-3DBE-8564-9A38418D5027> /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.13/libcoreclr.dylib
dyld: loaded: <2A0E160E-9EE6-3B23-8832-6979A16EC250> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
dyld: loaded: <E59859C6-7221-3324-BB58-F910B2199959> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
dyld: loaded: <B377D7C7-EDB6-3737-B492-E9872F4C6469> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
dyld: loaded: <D939A124-9FD5-37A2-B03B-72E98CBC98FE> /usr/lib/libfakelink.dylib
dyld: loaded: <8F8D8A8B-4EE0-3C09-9F45-725A1FBDD38C> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: <EF2AC5FF-B98D-3252-ABA8-2FC721CBA942> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftLinking.framework/Versions/A/SoftLinking
dyld: loaded: <04A917FB-DBFB-3432-BA4C-5B860990A420> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
dyld: loaded: <6B70B98B-BCC5-3FBE-A6B5-CD0696AA055A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
dyld: loaded: <B857EADF-D517-34E8-8053-34C0E6695250> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
dyld: loaded: <49187239-597B-31A1-8895-8AA265C818C7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
dyld: loaded: <8D30829B-426E-361E-B2A9-5850F1E5513D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
dyld: loaded: <6243D4C0-3572-30A6-889A-B8690A5EAC24> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
dyld: loaded: <9B6B42DB-8768-343B-B10E-A9A5710280CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
dyld: loaded: <9ACD5692-3B92-3E6E-8B24-56ADCC911556> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
dyld: loaded: <5D0B1BB2-995B-32EB-AE75-F5F27127ACAF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
dyld: loaded: <C861FAD6-D3A5-302C-88AE-B2813F7201A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
dyld: loaded: <49AC0177-35A3-3C96-AD9D-3E59923C4761> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
dyld: loaded: <3518EA0E-C32D-32CC-81B9-0F3C83B6430C> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
dyld: loaded: <A2F6DE8D-2B38-3669-A16E-E1BD54108F24> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
dyld: loaded: <A3F1E999-6D61-32D7-B3F7-67832CEA53CD> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
dyld: loaded: <ACCC6A4C-3257-38A4-8AFB-BA73D906205B> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
dyld: loaded: <6E2BD7A3-DC55-3183-BBF7-3AC367BC1834> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: <8D9081B3-3F6A-31A0-9B20-1AE5CD8DD747> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
dyld: loaded: <20EDB261-69C7-3E4A-8C00-878814186A62> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
dyld: loaded: <33A9FBF3-A2D3-3ECE-9370-B0ADDE3896DE> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
dyld: loaded: <D71EF121-D4B0-306E-9843-9FAFD558E3A4> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: <DE05C188-D9FE-30DC-8299-DF3DC9F837A5> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
dyld: loaded: <C4C7A5DC-C3AD-374D-902A-B6DED14FBB67> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
dyld: loaded: <879A04AA-F9A1-3640-A9EF-F5D0813C852A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/Versions/A/AppleFSCompression
dyld: loaded: <B33BEF87-3275-356D-9815-D0E94122D2EB> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
dyld: loaded: <80AF345B-1989-3C88-AEF4-8FF18A366A9C> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
dyld: loaded: <FA3308D0-E7B4-3A2C-AE39-0E085F6CDEE0> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: <FAA7B36E-21EC-3ADF-AA6A-E3742737CA3A> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: <7A2E42E6-3AF2-3ECB-8A16-5C4AC41206EE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAutoLayout.framework/Versions/A/CoreAutoLayout
dyld: loaded: <9C42DB2C-0A6D-38CE-BB8D-899A9B34B695> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
dyld: loaded: <ACFCD23E-05DF-3F96-BCFA-E294AAAFD2CE> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
dyld: loaded: <9061C767-43FD-3483-9C48-73973AF82DC1> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E0BF29C7-869B-3DD5-82AE-F36E6398091A> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E8044658-AE79-3930-A902-07A38BB22382> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
dyld: loaded: <970D1F7B-5DBD-355F-80D8-C820AA1626D2> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
dyld: loaded: <DE5787F8-D011-3E71-8323-936B35976D9E> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: <97EB5DFD-BB41-3834-BF09-1F597D84F324> /usr/lib/libdns_services.dylib
dyld: loaded: <168D84A7-8E54-361E-9161-B661D96C0C9A> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E163D5F9-E202-3A53-817B-8BC40B9293C0> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: <AD10ECF4-E137-3152-9612-7EC548D919E8> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: <D14F9D24-693A-37F0-8F92-D260248EB282> /usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: <4F8A1D06-3EFF-3174-BE9C-C4B70A3EA290> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSystemInfo.framework/Versions/A/AppleSystemInfo
dyld: loaded: <B15E9DA1-1C81-3ECF-94C7-FD137AD6C5E2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/Versions/A/IOMobileFramebuffer
dyld: loaded: <029C5E16-2E04-3E98-BE25-CC8BAE5E3D19> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
dyld: loaded: <74E17BB2-1A3C-3574-92DD-63ABE39E3FF9> /usr/lib/libCheckFix.dylib
dyld: loaded: <2F48471B-68F3-3017-8B18-BEDD4ED5853F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
dyld: loaded: <6C49B26B-CB39-3504-AD5E-9C3333FFE086> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreNLP.framework/Versions/A/CoreNLP
dyld: loaded: <FB7BF527-2D95-3E82-AAD8-D42B33DAC0F0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetadataUtilities.framework/Versions/A/MetadataUtilities
dyld: loaded: <102A0AD8-D119-340B-B652-B75F0AAB1C7E> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
dyld: loaded: <01B968D9-A464-3667-8B8E-C99AEBA1FF79> /System/Library/Frameworks/MLCompute.framework/Versions/A/MLCompute
dyld: loaded: <2423F0F6-A3A4-37AB-971E-FCFC7645D282> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
dyld: loaded: <1F424683-4213-3594-9BF5-EFCCCDAA83A5> /usr/lib/libmecab.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E40EFA11-E95C-36D1-A8BE-8CA5B1DD179D> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
dyld: loaded: <47CDE3EE-60AB-38CE-9494-5CC047CACA7F> /usr/lib/libThaiTokenizer.dylib
dyld: loaded: <718400BF-9911-3CB6-8CCE-4C2D7C35D80A> /usr/lib/libChineseTokenizer.dylib
dyld: loaded: <F37DBCE9-20CD-33D4-806B-93B326E08422> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/MetalPerformanceShaders
dyld: loaded: <829B9C4D-2DB6-38C9-9FE8-E6544FB3BDCC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal
dyld: loaded: <3EBF95E1-30EB-3162-A9D4-B97BE581B69F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
dyld: loaded: <8CD6F55A-8E4F-3653-A367-427D0ED3DD16> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
dyld: loaded: <9D11FCFC-6C30-32B6-864B-9CC3ED7D1143> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
dyld: loaded: <4CCEE561-A72B-33BC-B9F9-77A6CF2E7AF0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
dyld: loaded: <92702864-A5C6-3E22-86F6-DB329532674A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
dyld: loaded: <2F92E8CD-396D-3665-88EB-41A4E1A9CB31> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
dyld: loaded: <0D017F3F-6FD6-38DB-AA14-A64523A4D093> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
dyld: loaded: <FC45F7FD-6B10-3F8D-A553-F57C757F6717> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
dyld: loaded: <55EE1866-623B-3C10-91FB-C8B06EB83995> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
dyld: loaded: <C5CD30D8-114B-3104-9020-E5C05E68CEE8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
dyld: loaded: <B889DE4E-7356-3CC8-A13E-68D15E2024DF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
dyld: loaded: <287C79B5-4E13-3DF6-BDC4-439EC621E010> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MPSCore.framework/Versions/A/MPSCore
dyld: loaded: <D009508B-DCDF-3421-B1CB-40FDF4A68E93> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MPSImage.framework/Versions/A/MPSImage
dyld: loaded: <8FA469B3-48BE-315B-B3A0-C868CD541608> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MPSNeuralNetwork.framework/Versions/A/MPSNeuralNetwork
dyld: loaded: <B988D5F6-4E54-335D-A654-12C74FD668EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MPSMatrix.framework/Versions/A/MPSMatrix
dyld: loaded: <613BB6F1-3588-3E25-B523-059022FBE56E> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MPSRayIntersector.framework/Versions/A/MPSRayIntersector
dyld: loaded: <51ECDE6B-39F8-3BAB-ADC1-84C958F40A3F> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MPSNDArray.framework/Versions/A/MPSNDArray
dyld: loaded: <B1FDD261-7707-3E20-A6C2-99D9AF46356B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetalTools.framework/Versions/A/MetalTools
dyld: loaded: <E6C1A91D-4ADE-33CB-AA47-2F573811BFD9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/Versions/A/AggregateDictionary
dyld: loaded: <4FFF906A-FE79-38F9-B777-AE878A0C99F1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/Versions/A/CoreAnalytics
dyld: loaded: <4A637FE0-A740-32F0-AE70-4593F6DF1573> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSauce.framework/Versions/A/AppleSauce
dyld: loaded: <41EDF102-E1B5-3FBA-A74A-6C583CAA5D24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/Versions/A/IOAccelerator
dyld: loaded: <44489BD1-3963-35DF-86F1-DE95778AC0DB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreFSCache.dylib
dyld: loaded: <1A05BCD7-232F-3950-936D-EC0F95BA3FB0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
dyld: loaded: <D43F3FFA-6692-3D56-ACBA-DDA40C566DDE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/Versions/A/CoreEmoji
dyld: loaded: <B059FF7F-731A-38F1-884A-588C6C8CA7F2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinguisticData.framework/Versions/A/LinguisticData
dyld: loaded: <2F429EBD-1BD2-3057-B760-8A81546DBD6F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Versions/A/Lexicon
dyld: loaded: <A5D1EBB3-70A1-3ECA-A3C7-E97FBAD36ECF> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
dyld: loaded: <25F138F8-9E55-3749-8271-0FDB275C3E2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
dyld: loaded: <333A7F2E-0F3E-37F1-9E1B-69996F5084D2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
dyld: loaded: <E48CCAAC-34B5-377E-8E5D-06CDBD411C2F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/APFS.framework/Versions/A/APFS
dyld: loaded: <72AC63B1-0B72-394F-97E8-BA9B114DD0A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
dyld: loaded: <0A268749-08E7-3551-8969-442210651CCA> /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
dyld: loaded: <2BBB708C-4D91-364E-ABD0-39BF198688A6> /usr/lib/libapp_launch_measurement.dylib
dyld: loaded: <89992991-8538-380B-B2B8-4EA997CBFDBE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesStore
dyld: loaded: <FD031028-B702-3909-B2AF-3916404DD4A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
dyld: loaded: <1C5219FB-B504-3658-B23B-2C45A3BA28F1> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: <EC15118E-62BD-3C24-A880-3B9B74318B0B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement
dyld: loaded: <D9E83280-D3C8-39F7-9F1B-6A08DB4AE9EB> /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.13/libclrjit.dylib
dyld: loaded: <588954D5-F840-3435-8489-7765CE36B2F0> /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.13/System.Native.dylib
dyld: loaded: <A3F4E2B3-9124-3C1A-B59C-D14383495A32> /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.13/System.Globalization.Native.dylib
dyld: loaded: <E099F89A-8E25-3206-871E-35948D04D185> /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.13/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.dylib
```

Comment: And where is this dll located?

Comment: A string in c++ is either a array of one character or two characters terminate with a '\0'.  See following for passing strings to c++ : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings

Comment: Also, what is `PAApi.dll`? Is it built for Windows? And are you running this on a Mac?

Comment: it's locate within project root

Comment: @NPras there is a doc mention that it's `Note that PA API is using __cdecl calling convention` so I think it's built for Linux or Mac as well...

Comment: additional info.. when decompile the dll, `PE32 executable (DLL) (GUI) Intel 80386`

Comment: What about it's dependencies, do you have those also